# I am getting the error no match for operator >> in the following function. What's wrong?

Tags: c++

```
void GetarrayElements(int a[]){
  int k=0;

  while (true){
    cout <<"to exit just type a value which is above 100 like ex. 101" << endl;
    cout<< "give me the "<< k <<"th element ";
    cin >> a[k] >> endl;
    if (a[k]<=100 && a[k]>=0){
      k+=1;
    }
    else{
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

I am trying to read some input values between 0 and 100 inclusive into an array and i got this error. "no match for operator >>". What can be wrong?

Answer (score 11):

`endl` can only be applied to output streams such as `cout`; you cannot use it on `cin`.

Answer (score 5):

Don't read into the read-only item "`endl`".

Change this:

```
cin >> a[k] >> endl;
```

...to this:

```
cin >> a[k];
```

Answer (score 2):

```
ostream& endl ( ostream& os );
```

You cannot pass in a istream instance (std::cin in our case) to endl.